# How to create exe file with database in c# to run on client machine

Tags: c#

I am creating a C# windows form application, the working can be summarized as users fills some form and data is saved in SQL database. Now the problem I am facing is that I have to deliver this as an executable file to someone. But the problem is database is creating issues as the connection string is not match with that computer. I know that if a distribute projects I can put connection string in app.config and every user can change it according to his/her machine. But i want to make it more convenient for the user not to change the connection string as i am only giving the executable file to client. as i have the connection string in my project is

```
String ConString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=D:\Users\khan\Desktop\MyApp\MyApp\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

So how to make it generic so that the client does not need to change the connections string. Kindly elp me out in this issue.I have searched a lot but still not done with it.

Comment: Build the connection string from within your program code and pass it into the constructor for your `SqlConnection` or Entity Framework context.

Comment: Is it always the same provider (i.e. a LocalDB)? Is it the InstanceName/file path that is changing or are there more settings that needs to be changed in the connectionstring?

Comment: string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a [Enviroment Variable](http://www.askvg.com/list-of-environment-variables-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/) instead of a fixed path in `AttachDbFilename`.

For example `%APPDATA%\Database1.mdf.`